# Obtener datos hijos y sus descendencias

Tags: php, laravel

Esta es una consulta más que nada.

Trabajando con PHP, hace un tiempo se me presento el siguiente problema:
Tengo una tabla **A** que tiene un campo **A.PADRE_ID** que es el **ID** de una fila de la misma tabla **A** (como por ejemplo un árbol).
Se necesita obtener todos los hijos y sus descendencias de un *id* (padre) de la tabla **A**.

Para esto, generé un bucle *for* para iterar sobre todas filas que tengan el `padre_id = id`, y dentro del bucle llamé a los *id* hijos y los añadí al arreglo que recorre el *for*.

ejemplo básico:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arreglo); $i++) {
    $hijos = A::wherePadreId($arreglo[$i])->pluck('id');
    array_merge($arreglo, $hijos);
}
```

Mi consulta es, ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de realizar esto?.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara, te sugiero leer [ask], considera editar y mostrar la estructura de tus tablas, la relación entre ellas y el resultado que esperas obtener

Comment: creo que es mejor usar una relacion hasMany, eloquent ya hace todo el trabajo por ti de una forma mas limpia